# Cookies And Subdomain

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

There is a website with several subdomains.
On the main subdomain cookies are set:

```
 @setcookie( $name, $value, $expires, '/', '.www.mysite.com');
```

I can see the cookie on www.mysite.com and sub1.mysite.com.
The directories are:

- www.mysite.com: public/index.php
- sub1.mysite.com: public/sub1/index.php

How can that be possible that I can't see it in the new subdomain sub2.mysite.com?

sub2.mysite.com public/sub2/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Setting the domain to 'www.example.com' or '.www.example.com' will
>   make the cookie only available in the www subdomain.

If you want to make the cookie available on all subdomains of example.com (including example.com itself) then you'd set it to **'.example.com'**.

Answer (score 1):

make sure the path is set to / so it works for the whole site, otherwise it might not work for sub directories on your site

Answer (score 0):

1. Using @ is not a wise act in general but using it in front of setcookie() is exceptionally *unwise*, if not to say a stronger word.
2. Subdomain should be set to .mysite.com'
3. path should be **set**, not omitted. If you want to have access to the cookie in any directory, set path to `/`.
4. Nevertheless, the reason can be any. One have **to debug**  their code, not asking for the possible reasons.

Comment: thank you for -1 and advices (though the function was not written by me, copypasted it from code written before me)

Comment: -1 is not for the function but for the way you posted: not a real code you run. So, there is no reason to answer at all, as there can be any number of the further corrections.